# Extract from Active Directory last password change and test if 6 month

Tags: powershell, dc

I try to extract form my DC user list with last password change and compare this date to the current days. Test if 10 Day before 6 month pass my test "if doesn't work, I think there is format date problem But I don't know. Can you help me ?

```
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GROUP" -Recursive | 
         Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName,Mail,PasswordLastSet | 
         Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,Mail,PasswordLastSet 

foreach ($user in $users) 
{
    if ( Get-Date.addDays(-10) -gt $($user.PasswordLastSet).AddDays(180) )
    {
        Write-Output $($user.SamAccountName) $($user.PasswordLastSet)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Get-Date.addDays(-10)` is wrong and should be `(Get-Date).AddDays(-10)`.

I would also suggest to drop the time part from that by using `(Get-Date).AddDays(-10).Date` so it effectively sets that reference date to midnight.

The `Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,Mail,PasswordLastSet` is redundant in this case.

Try something like this:

```
$refDate = (get-Date).AddDays(-10).Date

# Get-ADGroupMember can return users, groups, and computers. 
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GROUP" -Recursive | 
         Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } |
         Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress, PasswordNotRequired, PasswordLastSet

foreach ($user in $users) {
    if (!$user.PasswordNotRequired) {  # some users may not need to have a password?
        if ($refDate -gt $user.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(180)) {
            Write-Output "$($user.SamAccountName) $($user.PasswordLastSet) $($user.EmailAddress)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

great, it works except for an error but i think it's beacause of user.passewordLastSet

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10).Date

$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GROUP" -Recursive | 
         Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress, PasswordNotRequired, PasswordLastSet


foreach ($user in $users) {
    if (!$user.PasswordNotRequired) {  # some users may not need to have a password?
         if ($user.PasswordLastSet) {
            if ($refDate -gt $user.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(180)) {
                Write-Output "$($user.SamAccountName) $($user.PasswordLastSet) $($user.EmailAddress)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From Theo's answer you would only change `if ($refDate -gt $user.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(180))` for `if ($refDate -gt $user.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(180) -and $user.PasswordLastSet)`. Also note, if the code provided was not working, comment on his answer providing details on why it's not working instead of posting a new answer with a copy of his code.